# data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Tags: database, postgresql, exception

I tried to execute the following command (Postgresql):

```
ALTER TABLE authentication ADD CONSTRAINT overlapping_times EXCLUDE USING GIST
(method with =,
 authenticator with =,
 box(point(extract(epoch FROM validfrom at time zone 'UTC'),extract(epoch FROM validfrom at time zone 'UTC') ),
     point(extract(epoch FROM validuntil at time zone 'UTC'), extract(epoch FROM validuntil at time zone 'UTC'))) WITH &&
)
```

and I got the  following error message:

```
ERROR:  data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

I did quite extensive googling still I am unable to translate this to plain English. What should I do to execute the command above?
The type of "method" is character varying, "authenticator" is text, "validfrom", "validuntil" are dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `authenticator` and `method`, use a plain unique constraint.  text and varchar() are identical for indexing purposes.

This means three alter table statements instead of one, but it should save you these problems.  Box should support GiST properly so you should be good there.

In plain English the error is telling you that the data type does not support the index operations expected of the index type.  So text strings can't be searched via an index as to whether they overlap, for example.  In other words the three cannot be put in the same constraint.

Additionally, keep in mind that UNIQUE constraints are faster than exclude constraints, so are preferred where they work.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was only necessary to install the extension first:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Comment: Very good and simple solution for me. Thanks.